# How to format bar_label with dollar sign and decimal

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I need to display the data above a seaborn barplot.  The numbers represent dollars and I would like to display the value `25200` as `$25.2k`.

This is the code I currently use to display the below graph.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

i = sns.barplot(ax = axes[1,0], x=lr_2021['decile'], y=np.round((lr_2021['NonCAT Severity']/1000),2), color = 'purple')
i.bar_label(axes[1,0].containers[0])
```

Which displays this:

[image]

I tried adding the following to the `bar_label` line:

```
i.bar_label(axes[1,0].containers["$",0, "K"])
```

That error'd out however.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you *only* need to add a `$` prefix and `K` suffix, the `fmt` param is simplest:

```
i.bar_label(axes[1,0].containers[0], fmt='$%gK')
```

But in this case, you also need to divide the values by 1000. That's too complex for `fmt`, so instead apply an f-string to the container's `datavalues` via the `labels` param:

```
bars = axes[1,0].containers[0]
i.bar_label(bars, labels=[f'${value/1000:.1f}K' for value in bars.datavalues])
```